# Arrangements of affine hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Fix $n>0$ and $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$. Call a function $f:X\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ **linear** if it is of the form
$$
f(\bar{x})=a_1x_1+\ldots+a_nx_n+b
$$
for some $a_i,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now suppose we have linear functions $f_1,\ldots,f_t$ and $g_1,\ldots,g_t$ with the following property:

For all $i\in\{1,\ldots,t\}$ and for all $\bar{x}\in X$,

$$
\textrm{there are }j,k\in\{1,\ldots,t\}\textrm{ such that }f_i(\bar{x})\leq g_j(\bar{x})\textrm{ and }f_k(\bar{x})\leq g_i(\bar{x}).
$$

Is it true that there must be some $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,t\}$ such that $f_i(\bar{x})\leq g_j(\bar{x})$ for all $\bar{x}\in X$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $f_i(\bar x)\leq g_j(\bar x)$?

Comment: All of the functions are maps to  $\mathbb{R}$, so it's just the ordering there.

Comment: For $n=1$, this seems to be true. Unfortunately, I don't know about the general case. Are you interested in seeing a proof of this special case though?

Comment: I think I understand the $n=1$ case, since there we can use the ordering on $X$. I am also more mystified by the general case. But if want to post a proof of $n=1$, then that is good too.

Comment: Where are the hyperplanes of the title?

Comment: The graph of a linear function can be thought of as an affine hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's treat the case $n=1$.

Assume that it is not true that there exist $i,j$ such that $f_i \leq g_j$ on all of $X$.
Then for every pair $i,j$ we can choose $x_{ij} \in X$ such that $f_i(x_{ij}) > g_j(x_{ij})$. Let $a=\min_{i,j}(x_{ij})$ and $b=\max_{i,j}(x_{ij})$.

Upon renumbering the $g_i$ if necessary, we can assume that $g_1(a)$ is the smallest value one of the $g_i$ attains at $a$. By assumption there exists $k$ such that $f_k(a) \leq g_1(a)$, and our assumption on $[a,b]$ above assures that $f_k(b) > g_1(b)$ (as $f_k$ and $g_1$ intersect in $[a,b]$, and lines can intersect at most once). Hence there must exist $j$ such that $f_k(b) \leq g_j(b)$. Again by the construction of $[a,b]$ there exists $\xi \in [a,b)$ such that $f_k(\xi) > g_j(\xi)$. In particular we must have $g_j(a) < f_k(a) \leq g_1(a)$, which contradicts minimality of $g_1(a)$.

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea to approach this differently, and after fighting it, took a simpler case where each $f$ or $g$ has only one element that is non zero, in the hope that this is still useful and suggests a path to the general case.

For the case when each $f$ or $g$ has only one element that is non zero (i.e. the planes are 'axis' aligned):

Given an index $p$, up to $n$, we can construct a vector $\bar v$ in $X$ with a 1 in the $p$ position and otherwise $0$s, and following the direction of $\bar v$ there is some point beyond which a function $f$` having the largest negative value in position p becomes (and remains) the minimum function $f$.

This gives us a lower bound for components in the $p$ position for all functions in $g$ - since any $g$ that has a lower value in the $p$ position will eventually fall below and remain below $f$` in the direction of $\bar v$, and thus break an assumption.

Heading in the reversed direction of $\bar v$, we can find a point at which the same $f \prime$ (or some parallel $f\prime\prime$ above it with equal largest negative component in position $p$) becomes and remains the maximum $f$ function. Since $f \prime$ and $f \prime\prime$ share the component in position p we are interested in, we will take the case where $f \prime$ is the upper function, without loss of generality.

Since we know there must be at least one function $g \prime$ which is eventually above $f \prime$ and remains above $f \prime$ in this direction by assumption (since there are a finite number of $g$, eventually at least one $g \prime$ must remain above $f \prime$ to infinity), we know this $g \prime$ must have a value in the p position of not more than that of that of $f \prime$, since otherwise it will eventually fall below $f \prime$.

So now we have a maximum bound for the position p for $g \prime$, and since it is equal to the minimum bound we have above for all g in this position, we have an equality for this position p in (at least one) $g \prime$.

The conclusions then follows since for each position $p$, we determine that the function $f \prime$ which has the minimum value of all $f$ in this position, has some $g \prime$ parallel and $\ge$ to it (possibly also parallel and $\ge$ to some parallel $f \prime\prime$ above it).

*Note: I think it can be argued similarly for each position $p$ from both the maximum positive and minimum negative values in $f$, since both will force this situation for some $g$.*

I think the underlying idea also works for the general case, but requires taking combinations of multiple positions and allowing for $g$ that are parallel to intersections of planes, and I've not managed to find a clean (and reasonably short) way to attack that yet.

Comment: Here is a counterexample to the claim that we can always remove $f_{k+1}$ and $g_{k+1}$: Let $n=1$, $X=\mathbb{R}$, $k=1$, $f_1\equiv 2$, $g_1\equiv 1$, $f_2\equiv 0$, $g_2\equiv 3$. In fact this example shows why the seventh paragraph of your answer is incorrect. In particular, $f_2$ is the minimum $f_i$ and $g_2$ is not the minimum $g_i$, but removing $f_2$ creates a situation that does not satisfy the assumptions. So I think the seventh paragraph is where the first error is, unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying in this paragraph.

Comment: It would also seem that if your proof were correct, then after repeating the inductive step enough times, you could conclude that $f_1\leq g_1$ on $X$ always works. Moreover, we can reorder the $f_i$'s and $g_i$'s without changing the original assumptions. So it would then follow that $f_i\leq g_j$ works for any $i,j$, which is clearly problematic. Finally, your proof does not use the linearity of the functions at all. Without this assumption, it's not too hard to find a counterexample to the main question.

Comment: You're right, it is bunk. Thanks for reasoning it out. I had been feeling it came out too simple, and started pulling it apart today, but your comment shines the light on a few issues. I think the underlying idea of being able to remove some pair of lines to get t-1 lines for which the assumptions hold is based on the linearity, but this not being explicit in the proof should have been a warning sign. Sorry for any time wasted. Interesting problem by the way. I don't know why but I am fascinated by it. What caused you to ask it?

Comment: No time wasted here. I think the strategy of induction on $t$ and trying to argue that some pair can be removed is a good one. The question is a small part of a bigger research question that I have been working on, which doesn't require much linear algebra, except for this one part I am having trouble with. It might well be false, but I think that if even I could see a counterexample it would help me know what to do next.

Comment: I still think this is true, but have only attempted a special case in the answer above. The underlying idea is that the functions f define two regions at the top and bottom of space, which the functions g cannot intersect. In higher dimensions, and zooming far enough back these look like pyramids. The case given is where in the extreme, the (upper and lower) pyramid sides are axis aligned, and so are the functions g. I think the general case allows g which are aligned with the intersections (corners) of the pyramid too - but in higher dimensions the corners are also hyperplanes.